# How to generate the combination of numbers and characters in data step?

Tags: sas

Say I have 1,2,3,4 for column 1. A,B,C,D for column 2. Also I have column 3, the value should be 3 replicates of column 2.

So finally we should have 4x4x3=48 observations and three variables in the data set,

My question if I use `RAND` function in data step, can we use seed or other skills? I think that `seed` is only for number but I have number and character combinations.

Thanks for hint.

Comment: If you want to use character variables as random number seeds, convert them to numbers first, e.g. via the `rank` function.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use PROC PLAN or CALL ALLCOMB but a SQL query seems easiest to me. This would be a cross join.

```
Proc SQL;
Select t1.column1, t2.column2, t3.column3
From have as t1
Cross join have as t2
Cross join have as t3;
Quit;
```

Comment: RAND does random numbers you want all combinations, those are different things. The documentation for allcomb does show some ways to do this via a datastep.